# How to consume a windows service running on localhost:port in a private virtual machine from a web app deployed in azure app service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, windows-services, azure-virtual-machine, azure-appservice

I have tried the VNet Integration in the App service and what will be the ip address for connecting to the service in the vm from the web app deployed in the app service.

suppose the ip of the vm is x.x.x.x and the service is running at port no abc of localhost
so accessing the service form the vm is using localhost:abc

So, how can i access this service in an app service.

Comment: please let me know the clarification on the question if any. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the app service is connected(VNet Integration) to VNet1-Subnet1.
And the VM with private IP a.b.c.d that is hosting the windows service available on port x is hosted on VNet2-Subnet2. Ensure the connectivity(VNet peering/NSG/OS firewall) exists between two entities(app service and VM) using TCPPING 'a.b.c.d:x'. You could use the same 'a.b.c.d:x' to connect to windows service from App service.